# Cannot find module 'Scene' or its corresponding type declarations Spark AR

Tags: spark-ar-studio

Anyone has any idea why do I get these errors? It's the first time when I'm trying to write a script, do I need to setup something first? Because from what I found in their documentation, there is no need..

> Cannot find module 'Scene' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

> Cannot find module 'Patches' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

> Cannot find module 'Diagnostics' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

Thank you for your time!

[image: error]

**LATER EDIT**: it seems that this doesn't affect the script, because I can use functions like:

`Diagnostics.log('Hello world!');`

or

```
const [directionalLight] = await Promise.all([
  Scene.root.findFirst('directionalLight0')
]);
```

(maybe Visual Studio was waiting for a file similar to `package.json` from `npm`)

Answer (score 0):

Try to reopen all SparkAR and VSCode. It's crucial to open your script from inside SparkAR, then it should create tsconfig.json with all typings you need.